# $\mathbb{R} P^1$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R} P^2$ but is not a regular level set

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I would like if you help me in this exercise in what I'm a little stuck:

> Thinking of $S^1$ as the Equator in $S^2$, give an embedding of $\mathbb{R}P^1$ in $\mathbb{R} P^2$ but prove that $\mathbb{R} P^1$ is not the level set of any regular value of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} P^2\to \mathbb{R}$.

To give the embedding, I combined the diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R} P^1\to S^1$ induced by $z\mapsto z^2$, the embedding $\iota: S^1\to S^2$ given by $\iota(x,y)=(x,y,0)$ and the canonical projection (which is a local diffeomorphism) $\pi:S^2\to \mathbb{R} P^2$. But injectivity fails and I don't know how to correct the maps to get the embedding.

To prove the second part, if $\mathbb{R} P^1=f^{-1}(q)$ for $f:\mathbb{R} P^2\to\mathbb{R}$ smooth, $q\in \mathbb{R}$, I thought of using that $(df)_p$ vanishes if $p$ is a local maximum/minimum of $f$, and that $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is compact so $f$ achieves a maximum/minimum, so $(df)_p$ isn't surjective for all $p\in f^{-1}(q)$ so $q$ is not a regular value. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Learn about homogeneous coordinates. Embed by tacking on a zero as the last coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the embedding: take the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^2$ by the antipode map to get $\mathbb{R}P^2$; the image of the embedded (in $\mathbb{S}^2$) $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a copy of $\mathbb{R}P^1$. So in particular you **shouldn't use** the $z\mapsto z^2$ map to go from $\mathbb{R}P^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^2$. Think about covering maps.

For the second part: your argument makes no sense because $f|_{\mathbb{R}P^1} = q$ by your construction, and is constant on $\mathbb{R}P^1$. Again, you should use the covering map construction. You can lift $f$ from $\mathbb{R}P^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$. But then $df$ will have to point toward the south pole for half of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and toward the north pole for the other half.

Comment: I see, now I've put "$f:\mathbb{R} P^1\to \mathbb{R} P^2$ given by $f([x,y])=[x,y,0]$ and it works! 

Such a nonsense I've made in the second part. I understand that as $S^2$ is the universal covering of $\mathbb{R} P^2$ every smooth function $f: \mathbb{R} P^2\to\mathbb{R}$ can be lifted to a smooth function $\tilde{f}: S^2\to \mathbb{R}$,. I don't get the last phrase "$df$ will have to point toward the south pole for half of $S^1$ and toward the north pole for the other half." How do you conclude this? Thank you, sir!

Comment: Think about the antipode map on $\mathbb{S}^2$. Let $x$ be a point on the equator and $y$ be a point slightly north of it. Suppose $f$ is regular at $x$ and so $df(x) \neq 0$. Then we can assume without loss of generality that $f(y) > f(x)$. The antipode of $y$, however, is slightly south of the antipode of $x$ (the latter still sits on the equator). And hence $df$ must point in the opposite direction there.